# Place variable amount of buttons in a circle

Tags: android, android-button

I have a menu with several round image buttons.
For now the buttons are ordered vertically in
a LinearLayout. What i want to do is to place
the buttons in a circle. The amount of buttons
is variable:

[image]

How can i symmetrical place a variable amount of
buttons along a circle? Later the Buttons will
be dragable and when a button is dragged into
the center of the circle an activity is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is just a small code snipplet for custom circle layout :

```
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams modifyLayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp, int degree) {
        /**
         * Determine in Quadrant or on Axis
         * Using Android convention. Right X-axis is degree 0, growing clockwise.
         * */
        degree = degree % 360;
        if (degree &lt; 0) { // Make it positive
            degree += 360;
        }
        if (degree == 0) { // right x-axis. Right
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.center);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            lp.setMargins(radius, 0, 0, 0);
        } else if (degree > 0 && degree &lt; 90) { // Quadrant IV. Lower Right
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.center);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.center);
            // Determine margin. 
            lp.setMargins(getMarginX(degree), getMarginY(degree), 0, 0); 
        } else if (degree == 90) { // Bottom y-axis. Bottom
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.center); // Above Center.
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            lp.setMargins(0, radius, 0, 0);
        } else if (degree > 90 && degree &lt; 180) { // Quadrant III. Lower Left
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.center);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.center);
            // Determine margin. 
            lp.setMargins(0, getMarginX(degree - 90), getMarginY(degree - 90), 0);
        } else if (degree == 180) { // Right x-axis. Left
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.center);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, radius, 0);
        } else if (degree > 180 && degree &lt; 270) { // Quadrant II. Upper Left
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.center);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.center);
            // Determine margin. 
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, getMarginX(degree - 180), getMarginY(degree - 180));
        } else if (degree == 270) { // Top y-axis. Top
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.center); // Above Center.
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, radius);
        } else if (degree > 270 && degree &lt; 360) { // Quadrant I. Upper Right
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.center);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.center);
            // Determine margin. 
            lp.setMargins(getMarginX(360 - degree), 0, 0, getMarginY(360 - degree));
        }
        return lp;
    }
    /** X offset i.e. adjacent length */
    private int getMarginX(int degree) {
        return Math.abs((int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree)) * radius));
    }
    /** Y offset i.e. opposite length */
    private int getMarginY(int degree) {
        return Math.abs((int)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree)) * radius));
    }
}
```

[Here](http://blog.mikeweng.com/2013/06/on-android-circular-style-layout.html) is complete post . the above code basically tells how can we customize the layout and place controls there.

Output is :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the description in the link you provided does not work. The xml (activity_main.xml) has errors. But i can work with the idea ;)

Comment: i hv my self create circle layout with 5 elememts in it